# Regular and simple curves with the same support are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, curves, diffeomorphism

I would like to know if anyone knows a simple proof of the following statement:

> Let $\gamma: I \to \Bbb R^n$ and $\phi: J \to \Bbb R^n$ be curves such that:
>
> - $\gamma$ and $\phi$ are simple (i.e.: they are injective in the interior of $I$ and $J$ respectively);
> - $\gamma$ and $\phi$ are regular (i.e.: class $C^1$ with non-null derivative)
> - $\gamma$ and $\phi$ have the same support (i.e.: the same image)
>   then there exists a diffeomorphism relating the two curves (i.e.: they are *equivalent*).

I have built the candidate for the diffeomorphism by using the injectivity but I couldn't prove that it is continuous, let alone differentiable. I think it may have something to do with the theorem on the limit of the composition of functions but I have not managed to go further than that.

---

As always, any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First consider the two curves

$$\alpha:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2, t\mapsto (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t)),$$

$$\beta:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2, t\mapsto (\cos(2\pi (t-1/2)),\sin(2\pi (t-1/2))).$$

Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both simple and regular curves with the unit circle on the plane the common image. If $[0,1]$ is given the standard orientation and the unit circle is given the counterclockwise orientation, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are also orientation preserving. Any diffeomorphism $\Phi: [0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $\beta\circ \Phi=\alpha$ would have to preserve the boundary, but $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)=(1,0)$ and $\beta(0)=\beta(1)=(-1,0)$; thus $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not reparameterizations of each other.

For a positive proof let us assume that both $\gamma$ and $\phi$ are injective ($\dagger$) and that both $I$ and $J$ are compact intervals. Call $C$ the common image with positive length $\ell(C)$. Replacing $\phi$ by $\phi\circ \iota$ if necessary, where $\iota:J\to J$ is the affine diffeomorphism changing the orientation of $J$, we may assume that $\gamma(\min(I))=\phi(\min(J))$. By the hypotheses on $\gamma$ and $\phi$ they are of positive and finite length. Define the arclength function $\Lambda_{\gamma}: I\to [0,\ell(C)]$, by

$$\Lambda_\gamma: t\mapsto  \int_{\min(I)}^{t} \left|\dfrac{d\gamma}{dt}(\tau)\right|\, d\tau.$$

Note that $\ell(C)=\Lambda_\gamma(\max(I))=\Lambda_\phi(\max(J))$ by the definition of the length and the change of variables formula for integrals. Both $\gamma$ and $\phi$ are regular, thus the integrants involved are both continuous, and consequently both $\Lambda_\gamma$ and $\Lambda_\phi$ are $C^1$; by the regularity of $\gamma$ and $\phi$ the functions $\Lambda_\gamma$ and $\Lambda_\phi$ are also strictly increasing, hence are diffeomorphisms (in general $\Lambda_\gamma$ is a $C^k$ diffeomorphism if $\gamma$ is $C^k$). Then we have two $C^1$ parameterizations $\gamma\circ \Lambda_\gamma^{-1}, \phi\circ\Lambda_\phi^{-1}: [0,\ell(C)]\to C$ of unit speed with $\gamma\circ \Lambda_\gamma^{-1}(0)=\phi\circ\Lambda_\phi^{-1}(0)$. Thus they have to coincide, so that $\gamma$ and $\phi$ are reparameterizations of each other.

($\dagger$) A similar argument works if $\gamma$ and $\phi$ are simple but not injective, provided that the endpoints are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It almost seems like what I was looking for. Unfortunately there are some points that are not completely clear to me: first, I couldn't find where you used the fact that the curves are simple (without this hypothesis there are easy counter-examples to the thesis); second, I am not convinced that we can assume $\gamma (\min I) = \phi (\min J)$ because starting from different points I am not sure you could shift and glue the interval of definition of a regular curve while mantaining it regular.

Comment: @MatteoMenghini Indeed I have considered only the simplest case and there are a few cases to look into. Perhaps it would also be good to clarify what you mean by equivalence of curves (or disclose your sources); unless I am misinterpreting what you mean the statement does not seem to be correct as stated.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a statement claimed by my teacher during a lesson so I have no reference for it. As for the definition of equivalent curves: "we say that $\gamma : I \to \Bbb R^n$ and $\phi : J \to \Bbb R^n$, where $I,J$ are intervals, are **equivalent** iff there exists a diffeomorphism $\psi : I \to J$ such that $\gamma \circ \psi = \phi$"